# I need import Scripts to create JS class in react JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fingerprint

I have some sdk scripts that should be imported like this:

```
  <script src="../libs/async.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../libs/es6-shim.js"></script>
  <script src="../libs/websdk.client.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../libs/fingerprint.sdk.min.js"></script>
```

These are part of an SDK that allows me to interact with a biometric. I need to create a module in my project that from these scripts to then reuse it. It is a project of React JS.

Try importing them into the index.html that contains the class = 'app / root' and then create a folder controlers with a FingerSDK class and try to access the classes and methods contained in the SDK but it does not compile, it does not recognize anything, as if the scripts were not imported.

For example i try in index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Dashboard</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="root">

  </div>

  <script src="../production/libs/es6-shim.js"></script>
  <script src="../production/libs/websdk.client.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../production/libs/fingerprint.sdk.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../production/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And my module:

```
class FingerprintSDKTest {
  constructor( errM ) {


    this.deviceId = '' //'A7429977-B0D4-9640-9AF7-CC792A5989BD'
    this.fingerData = {}
    this.sdk = new Fingerprint.WebApi
    this.errorManagment = errM
    this.getDeviceList()

  }
  getDeviceList() {
    this.sdk.enumerateDevices()
      .then( response => {

        this.deviceId = response[0]
      } )
      .catch( err => {

        notification['warning']( {
          message: 'No se ha conectado el lector de huellas',
          description: 'No se ha detectado ningún lector de huellas, algunas funcionalidades no estaran disponibles sin el lector, favor de connectar un lector de huellas.'
        } )
      } )
  }
}
```

I need to be able to import those scripts so that I can instantiate FingerPrint.WebApi and I really do not understand how I can do it. After I need import this module into a React JS component.

I appreciate you can guide me and I appreciate the contributions, apologies for my English.

Comment: Why not simply use https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/

Comment: The project is created with create-react-app, I need to be able to import those scripts in my project so that FingerPrint.WebApi can be instantiated in that module that will be used in the rest of the application.

Comment: Can you post a link that API?

Comment: The SDK consists of the scripts that I am importing as shown in the html, I need to import those scripts in a ReactJS project to be able to create a module from it, there is no link, I only have those 3 scripts and a PDF document with the documentation of the methods they contain, knowing how to use them within reacting is enough, thank you very much!

Comment: FingerPrint WEBAPI... Now SDK... How to ask: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

> index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
        <meta
          name="description"
          content="Web site created using create-react-app"
        />
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
        <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
        <title>TestApp</title>`enter code here
      </head>
      <body>
        <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
        <div id="root"></div>
    </div>
      <script src="scripts/es6-shim.js"></script>
      <script src="scripts/websdk.client.bundle.min.js"></script>
      <script src="scripts/fingerprint.sdk.min.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

> BioAuth.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class BioAuth extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
     this.onScriptLoad();

}

onScriptLoad = () => {
    this.sdk = new window.Fingerprint.WebApi();
    this.sdk.onDeviceConnected = function (e) {
        console.log('no fingerprint device');
    };
    this.sdk.onDeviceDisconnected = function (e) {
        console.log('no fingerprint device');
    };
    this.sdk.onCommunicationFailed = function (e) {
        console.log('Communication Error')
    };
    }

  render() {
    return ( 
      <div>
        <h1>Validate BioAuth Connectivity</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default BioAuth;
```

With above config i use imported functions in my ReactJs Components.